# pandas series find index of a certain type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

one of the columns of my df contains mostly datetime.time types

```
all_cities['Result'].head()
0    02:19:53
1    02:20:10
2    02:20:52
3    02:37:19
4    02:38:05

Name: Result, dtype: object
```

but, all_cities['Result'][0]

```
datetime.time(2, 19, 53)
```

how can i find the index of cell of different types(not datetime.time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ex': [1, datetime.time(2,19,53), "string", [1,2,3]]})

    ex
0   1
1   02:19:53
2   string
3   [1, 2, 3]
```

You can do

```
df[df.ex.transform(type) == datetime.time]
```

To get

```
ex
1   02:19:53
```

---

*Details:*

`transform(type)` yields the type of your entries

```
0              <class 'int'>
1    <class 'datetime.time'>
2              <class 'str'>
3             <class 'list'>
```

Then

```
 df.ex.transform(type) == datetime.time

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
```