# Python - Pandas Describe Throwing Error: unhashable type 'dict'

Tags: python, json, pandas, socrata

Update:  I am using some example code from "Socrata Open Source API." I note the following comment in the code:

```
# First 2000 results, returned as JSON from API / converted to Python 
# list of dictionaries by sodapy.
```

I am not v. familiar with JSON.

I have downloaded a dataset, creating a DataFrame 'df' with a large number of columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)
```

When I attempt to use the describe() method, I get "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'":

```
df.describe()
...
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How can I identify the columns which are generating this error?

UPDATE 2: 
Per Yuca's request, I include an extract from the df:

[image]

Comment: can you include the results from `df.head()`?

Comment: if you are just trying to find out which columns are generating the error you could do a `for column in df` then use `df[column].describe()` since columns are just series and you can call describe on a series

Comment: @Yuca - Too many columns to include output of head.  What are you looking for?

Comment: @Thunderwood - Apologies, I am doing this in Juypter Notebook.  When I take your suggestion, there is no output.   Help?

Comment: the result of your dataframe constructor. `describe` is a built in so the only reason for it to fail is to have a distorted DataFrame

Comment: @Yuca - If you can talk me through getting the output of head in a concise format, I'll gladly do it!

Comment: we can slice the first 5 columns. so df.iloc[:10,:5]

Comment: @Yuca - see above.

Comment: Do any of your columns contain `dict` or dict-like values?

Comment: ok, so my guess is that since you're building from JSON, one of your columns contains an object of type 'dict'. Not sure how to help you find it. But I would bet that's the issue at hand

Comment: @Thunderwood - OK, so I took your suggestion (I had an error in your suggested implementation) and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @ G Anderson, @Yuca - Yes, it seems (at least) one column is an "object of type dict" (although I thought objects were there own type!).    But the questions is how to find it.  There are about 40 columns, and the brute force method is not appealing, nor is it enlightening.

Comment: You can start with `df.select_dtypes(object).columns` to find all columns with non-numeric dtypes

Comment: what does `df.dtypes` return?

Comment: @G Anderson, @ MrE - All objects.

Comment: This is unwieldy, but I can't figure out how to best turn it into a mask. This will give you each column and where it is a `dict`: `[df[i].transform(type) == dict for i in df.columns]` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459205/pandas-series-find-index-of-a-certain-type))

Comment: @G Anderson   This seems to return a boolean for EVERY element in the df. However, after scrolling through all the outputs, I have identified one column which seems to be the offender.    How would you reduce the output to a True or False for each column?   Some listwise OR?

Comment: @G Anderson - I think I figured out how to achieve this, thanks to G Anderson's comment above.   See my edited question above.  Thanks, everybody!

Answer (score 10):

I came across the same Problem today and did a bit research about different versions of pyarrow. [here](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/issues/414#issuecomment-499087343) I found that in the past (<0.13), pyarrow would write real columns of data for the index, with names.In the most recent version of pyarrow, there would be no column data, but a range index metadata marker instead. It means parquet files produced with newer version of pyarrow cant be read by older versions.

Comment: Installing the right version of pyarrow seems the solution

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the user community (h/t G Anderson), I pieced together a solution:

```
for i in df.columns:
if df[i].transform(type).any() == dict:
    df = df.drop(i, axis= 1)
```

transform(type).any() checks all elements in column i, and drops the column if the element is type dict.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

pandas0.25.3 is ok with reading json containing dicts, apparently pandas1.0.1 not so much

```
df = pd.read_json(path,lines=True)
TypeError: unhashable type: ‘dict’
```

Above is thrown by pandas1.0.1 for the same file for which it works in pandas0.25.3.

The issue is [tracked](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32409) and apparently fixed in master which I suppose will make it into the next version.